# roots of unity of a complex number without real part

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to Complex Variable, today I saw a theorem without any proof, the theorem is:

> If $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are n-th roots of unity then so is $\zeta_1\zeta_2$.

I don't really know how to prove this, and I assumed it is true, but I suddenly found that if I

> Let $z$ be a complex number that has no real part. If $\zeta_1$ and
> $\zeta_2$ are n-th roots of $z$ then so is $\zeta_1 \zeta_2$.

This statement is actually false, so my question is:

1. Can you give me a proof for the theorem?
2. What is wrong with the second statement?
   Many Thanks

Comment: What happens when you raise $\zeta_1\zeta_2$ to the $n$th power?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is wrong with the second statement"? You already know that it's false. Once you prove the first statement (which involves the step $1\cdot1=1$), you'll understand why the second statement wasn't promising.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for your reply, the reason why i know it is false is because i tried few examples, and it didnt work. My understanding is that all the roots of complex number will form roots of unity. i think i may have some misunderstanding towards this topic.

Comment: I think I just totally mess up with roots and roots of unity. The modulus of a root may not equal to 1, but the modulus of root of unity always equal to 1. Thanks everyone, i think i may get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are $n$-th roots of unity then by definition
$$\zeta_1^n=1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \zeta_2^n=1.$$
It follows that
$$(\zeta_1\zeta_2)^n=\zeta_1^n\zeta_2^n=1\cdot1=1,$$
which shows that $\zeta_1\zeta_2$ is an $n$-th root of unity.

---

Of course, when replacing $1$ by an arbitrary $z\in\Bbb{C}$, the argument fails, as $z\cdot z=z$ does not hold in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have one doubt, my understanding is that the roots of a complex number will always form a root of unity. Is this true?

Comment: This is false. A root of unity is a root of $1$.

Comment: Thank you! maybe I should review the definition again.